# iOS and Android, save values that persists after cache and data wiping

Tags: android, ios

I'm building a REST API that will serve some data to an Android and an iOS app.

When the user signs up (using his phone number) a code is sent to the device via SMS, this code is then fetched by the app or copied by the user and resent to the server to confirm the phone number.

After the phone number is confirmed the pair phone number (user) and code (password) can be exchanged for an access token for the API.

My only concern is: can Android and iOS apps persist data in a way that survives cache and app-data wiping? I don't want that SMS to be sent more than once per [phone number,device] pair. (it will eventually be sent again if the user changes it's phone number or logs in from a different device, that's fine)

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm not programming the app so I know little about iOS/Android development, but I must know if this kind of persistence exists in both platforms

Comment: a file on the device? not exactly secure though. there is nothing that survives from an app after uninstall aside from any files created

Comment: the application will have a hardcoded key used for HMAC authentication when accessing the public section of the API, maybe saving it encrypted to a file using that key? what do you think?

Comment: I think you'd be introducing a security issue if that were possible. if that token persisted through erasing data, then what's to prevent that token from being reused by another client? The token itself indicates that authentication has happened, its persistence effectively introduces a way to bypass authentication.

Comment: The key for HMAC stays hardcoded, what I'm saying should be saved to a file are username and password, encrypted using the key used for HMAC. To impersonate a user one should also find the hardcoded key to decrypt user and password and know the application public identifier (which is computed using device uuid and some other device params)... of course one can do all of that stuff so I wonder, how to handle that kind of scenario? it's a scenario similar to WhatsApp's, any of you know how they handle it?

Comment: Be aware that you cannot access a unique device identifier on iOS. There is `identifierForVendor` but it may change if your app is reinstalled or the device is reimaged.

Comment: not even IMEI, some MAC address, apple's UDIDs? I'm sure there are some immutable and unique parameters to be accessed... (I don't care how the app developers generate the public key, just as long as they guarantee it is unique amongst all iOS devices)